# Share Extension "Waiting to Attach"

Tags: ios, share-extension

I have suddenly come up against this issue with my share extension, both on the simulator and when I run it on a device. 

I run the extension from the scheme and I get the dialogue "Choose an app to run", I choose Photos and then when I go to the photos app and select to share I get the following message in the debug panel:

> *my_extension_Bundle_identifier* Waiting to Attach

This was working fine a while back, but suddenly I got this issue. Any ideas
[image: Selecting to run the extension]

[image: Sheme setup]

Comment: Exactly the same issue, was debugging it all the time like 2 weeks ago. Im stuck here now. Have you found a fix yet?

Comment: No, I haven't, found a solution

Comment: It's not working even after recreating Scheme and target. The deployment target for both share extension and the project is set to 12.0. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this issue by deleting the Share Extension Scheme and then AutoCreating it.
Additionally, the main storyboard reference in my Share Extension plist was wrong.